# Why my UI is not updated in current scenario by call to VM2 contructor by passing arguments to constructor

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I am stuck badly in a situation and don't know how to solve the problem. The situation is I have two views and each having corresponding ViewModel classes. (Lets say View1 and View2 and corresponding VM1 and VM2 classes )
The situation is  View1 should launch first and i read some input from user(some integer value) and then after that View2 has to launch. The problem is View2 has a UI which has to repeat number of times the user entered the integer value 1 step before in previous View1 launch inside a textbox. So you can see the UI of View2 depends upon the input taken at View1 launch.

So right at the time when the user entered the integer value the VM2 must be aware of that value so that VM1  will intialize the VM2 class  to repeat that ListBox (which contains UI) that many times.

My approach to do this is like this (which is obviously not working that's why i am here to take guidance from experienced MVVM guys).

I go to View2.cs class and before and call View1 there in MainWindow() just after InitializeComponent(); function so taht View1 will be launched before View2 will be launched. And i got the value from View1 here as user enters in it and then i pass to that value to VM2 constuctor (like this:vm = new ViewModel(age);)  so that my UI will be repeated, "age" variable times (please see the code below)

Lets say this my View2:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDialogWithReturnProperty.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vM="clr-namespace:MVVMDialogWithReturnProperty.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="850">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vM:ViewModel>            
        </vM:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Name="ButtonsContainer" Width="700" Height="600">
         <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding lb_GlobalList}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="0,30,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        //I have more UI here
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Grid.Row="2"  Width="60px" Height="25px" Name="savebtn" Margin="40,5,0,0"
             Click="savebtn_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In my View2.cs i try to do this so that i will get the integer value entered by View1

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();  //This will launch another Window which contains two textbox and textblocks.  "Title" and "Age"
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialog.RetVal != null)
            {
                string name = dialog.RetVal.Title;
                int age = dialog.RetVal.Age;
                ViewModel vm=DataContext as ViewModel;  
                vm = new ViewModel(age);// Here i get the integer variable "age" from View1 and i pass to the constructor of View2's VM2 (which is named as ViewModel in my case)

            }

        }
        private void savebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var viewModel = DataContext as ViewModel;
            Pyth py = new Pyth(viewModel);
            this.Close();

        }
    }
```

I am doing this thing vm = new ViewModel(age); because i think that it will call the VM2(ViewModel here) and will initialize my ListBox by number of "age"(integer value) times in its constructor beofre View2 Launches so that it will have UI repeating number of "Age" times by calling VM2's constructor like this :

```
  public ViewModel(int numberOfRepeatitions)
        {
            _canExecute = true;
            lb_GlobalList = new ObservableCollection<tablegenerateModel>();
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfRepeatitions; i++)
            {
                _lb_GlobalList.Add(lb_Global = new tablegenerateModel()
                {
                    Name = "table" + i,
                    //contains other UI also like Textbox, Textblocks etc.
                });

            }
        }
```

But what i found is the UI do not repeat that many times, It just repeats the number of time i initialized statically in parameterless ViewModel constructor but not this one "public ViewModel(int numberOfRepeatitions)".

**How to change the code such that i will have repeat UI of View2 that many times the user had entered "age"(integer value) in previous View1 launch.**

Comment: a view does not inform a view, a VM does inform a VM via Mediator/Eventagreagator (basically a lookuptabel). `Mediator.Inform(object/typ/interface,message);`

Comment: @WiiMaxx Ok.. Sorry that was mis-explanation, Now that you have read my question and understood it,  so could you please let me know how to solve the problem.. so that i read data from user in View1 launch and pass it VM2 so that UI repeats that many times before the launch of View2 ?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the event aggregator anymore. I prefer to inject a service in both VM and use it as a communication channel. The same instance would be injected in both VM, and as one could call a _NotifySettingsChanged_ method, the other VM could register to a _SettingsChanged_ event for instance. However,  you'll need to have a .ctor with parameters and can't instantiate your VM in xaml anymore.

Comment: @Fbio Thanks but it's very difficult to understand what you said.. Could you please give me one sample of it ? How will i pass the "age" (integer value) such that it will intialize the ListBox to repeat that intger variable "age" times ? Please explain bit more with an example

Comment: Maybe best to look for some good Messenger examples - here is one https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/